# docker is not reading from docker-compose.yml

Tags: php, docker, docker-compose, containers

It seems that when  i run `Docker compose up`, docker is not reading from `docker-compose.yml`.
It seems like it is loading images from cache or i don't think where is finding them.
Bellow is my docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'

services:
  httpd:
    image: httpd:latest
    user: root
    ports:
        - "80:80"   # Default Apache port (Default on PHP 7.4)
        - "8073:8073" # PHP 7.3 Apache port
        - "8074:8074" # PHP 7.4 Apache port
        - "8081:8081" # PHP 8.1 Apache port
    volumes:
        - ./:/var/www/html/myApp/:rw
        - ./dev/Docker/httpd/httpd.conf:/usr/local/apache2/conf/httpd.conf
    restart: on-failure
    container_name: httpd
    networks:
      - mb-frontend

  php8.1-fpm:
    build: ./dev/Docker/php-fpm/8.1
    user: root
    environment:
      XDEBUG_ENABLED: 1
      XDEBUG_REMOTE_HOST: host.docker.internal
      PHP_IDE_CONFIG: serverName=localhost
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www/html/myApp/:rw
    restart: on-failure
    container_name: php8.1-fpm
    networks:
      - mb-frontend
      - mb-backend

  php7.4-fpm:
    build: ./dev/Docker/php-fpm/7.4
    user: root
    environment:
      XDEBUG_ENABLED: 1
      XDEBUG_REMOTE_HOST: host.docker.internal
      PHP_IDE_CONFIG: serverName=localhost
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www/html/myApp/:rw
    restart: on-failure
    container_name: php7.4-fpm
    networks:
      - mb-frontend
      - mb-backend

  php7.3-fpm:
    build: ./dev/Docker/php-fpm/7.3
    user: root
    environment:
      XDEBUG_ENABLED: 1
      XDEBUG_REMOTE_HOST: host.docker.internal
      PHP_IDE_CONFIG: serverName=localhost
    volumes:
        - ./:/var/www/html/myApp/:rw
    restart: on-failure
    container_name: php7.3-fpm
    networks:
      - mb-frontend
      - mb-backend

  db:
    image: mariadb:10.3.5
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: myPassword
      MYSQL_USER: dev
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: myPassword
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    volumes:
      - /root/Bureau/mysql:/var/lib/mysql/:rw
      - ./dev/Docker/mariadb/conf.d/:/etc/mysql/conf.d/:rw
      - ./dev/Docker/mariadb/config/init.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init.sql
    restart: on-failure
    container_name: db
    networks:
      - mb-backend

  phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
    environment:
      PMA_HOST: db
    volumes:
      - /root/Bureau/phpmyadmin:/var/lib/mysql/
    networks:
      - mb-backend
    depends_on:
      - db

  redis:
    image: redis:6.2
    container_name: redis
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"
    networks:
      - mb-backend
networks:
  mb-frontend:
    driver: bridge
  mb-backend:
    driver: bridge
```

I commented some images on `docker-compose.yml` but when i tape the command `Docker compose up` on terminal, all images even commented images are Up.
Can anyone help me how i force docker to read images from the edited docker-compose.yml

Comment: I don't know if this is related, but the command is `docker-compose up`

Comment: Can you reduce this to a [mcve]; what's the minimum `docker-compose.yml` you need to run this, what are you changing, what command exactly are you running, and what effect do you see?

Answer (score 2):

Good practice would be do use:

> docker compose down

and then

> docker compose up

**UPDATE:**

Next I would suggest to clean up your containers:

List all containers:

> docker ps -a

Remove those you don't want because they might still be in the system

> docker rm <CONTAINER ID/NAME>

[How to Stop & Remove a running container by ID or Name?](https://thispointer.com/docker-how-to-stop-remove-a-running-container-by-id-or-name/)

Comment: I have the same issue. I have commented the image of phpMyAdmin and i run the command 'docker compose up'. The container of phpMyAdmin is up

Comment: I had removed all containers and when i run docker compose up, the phpMyAdmin container is Up. I had even deleted it from docker-compose.yml

Answer (score 1):

The command is actually `docker compose up`.
The command `docker-compose` has been deprecated as of latest version. We can now use `docker compose` without the hyphen(-).

You can use `docker-compose -f <path-to-compose-file>` to pass in the compose file.

**Example:**

```
docker compose -f docker-compose.yml up
```

Reference documentation: https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/

Comment: It is the same thing. I had commented phpMyAdmin image and when i run the command with the option -f and the name of the docker-compose file, the phpMyAdmin container is up